# Calendar adding while in a for loop causing ArrayList overwrite previous values

Tags: java, android, arraylist, calendar

The values from `tempC` are correctly generated (already debugged), but when inserted into the "days" list (already tried simple Array, Linked List and ArrayList), they overwrite the previous value and add the new one.

Let me illustrate:

> --> "days" have one Calendar with the value 03/26/2016 
>   --> a new value "04/25/2016" is added to the collection 
>   --> "days" now have two Calendars, but instead of "03/26/2016" and "04/25/2016" they have the values "04/25/2016" and "04/25/2016" 
>   --> It keeps going like this with every iteration, always adding the new Calendar and overwriting all the previous ones with the new one

**Here's the code snippet:**

```
public LinkedList<Calendar> days = new LinkedList<Calendar>();

private void calculateCreditReturn(){
    Calendar tempC = Calendar.getInstance();
    for(int x=0; x<parcels; x++){
        tempC.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
        days.add(tempC);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Calendar` is mutable, and if you have only one object....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
public LinkedList<Calendar> days = new LinkedList<Calendar>();

private void calculateCreditReturn(){

   Calendar tempC = Calendar.getInstance();
    for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
        tempC.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
        Calendar forStore = (Calendar) tempC.clone();
        days.add(forStore);
    }
}
```

Rather than storing tempC, we create a clone called `forstore` that we are storing in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same object on the list.

In your case:

```
tempC -> 03/26/2016
list = [tempC]
Change tempC: tempC -> 04/25/2016
list = [tempC, tempC]
```

So, basically, you must create another Calendar object before adding it to the list.